# For loop for multiple UITextFields

Tags: for-loop, uitextfield

I have multiple UITextFields and I'm making the same changes to the border, radius and color.

```
@IBOutlet weak var answer1Text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answer2Text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answer3Text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answer4Text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answer5Text: UITextField!

self.answer1Text.layer.cornerRadius = 5
self.answer1Text.layer.borderWidth = 2

let borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 125.0/255.0, green:210.0/255.0, blue: 238.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.answer1Text.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
```

Repeating the code five times for each textfield is very inefficient. I was thinking a for loop would be the best solution but I can't figure out how to replace the int in the text field name. For example,

```
for var i = 0; i < 6; i++ {
    self.answer1Text.layer.cornerRadius = 5 // Not sure how to replace the 1 here
}
```

If a for loop is the best solution, how do you do so? If not, what's the best way to implement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all your answerTexts to `NSArray` and loop through this array. In iteration of loop you can reach to your `UITextField` object from an array by index and set your properties:

```
var answerTextsArray = [self.answer1Text, self.answer2Text, self.answer3Text, self.answer4Text, self.answer5Text]
for var i = 0; i < answerTextsArray!.count; i++ {
    var myTextField = answerTextsArray[i]
    myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2
    let borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 125.0/255.0, green: 210.0/255.0, blue: 238.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    myTextField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
}
```

Comment: This worked and it also gave me an idea for another solution below, which I finally ended up using.  

var textFields = [answer1Text, answer2Text, answer3Text, answer4Text, answer5Text]

for textField in textFields {
 textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2 
        let borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 125.0/255.0,        green: 210.0/255.0, blue: 238.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)       textField.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        }